# down casting an element of a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift, downcast

When I try to downcast an element of a dictionary, I get a syntax error:

```
let adDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = DidonWebServices.sharedInstance.adAtIndex (indexPath.row)


let titleString = adDict["description"] as? String      // error: 'String' is not a subtype of '(String, AnyObject)'
```

If I replace the previous line by:

```
let title:AnyObject? = adDict["description"]
let titleString = title as? String
```

the compiler is happy and the code is working.

I don't understand the compiler error. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `subscript` in `Dictionary` returns an optional:

```
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

Meaning you have to unwrap the optional before you can downcast:

```
let titleString = adDict["description"]! as? String
```

As of Beta 3 you can access the value directly without downcasting, like this:

```
let titleString = adDict["description"]
```